# asus webcam is flipped upside down everywhere

Tags: asus, webcam, v4l

I've been having this problem and I haven't been able to solve it for days now. It should be very simple, but I'm also very much a novice.

My webcam is flipped upside down. Tried flipping it back with v4l2, but the settings doesn't apply. In Cheese I can manually flip the webcam but the effect doesn't generalize to other applications, such as firefox/chrome or skype.

I know that internal ASUS cameras are physically installed upside-down and that there is software to flip it, but it seems v4l isn't able to do it.

The common solution for skype, `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype` doesn't fix the problem either.

Except actually turning my computer upside down, what options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

> **UPDATE**: Since the new skype app is basically a WebApp this solution
>   won't work with Skype for Linux Beta (Skype 5.0+). Also many functions
>   present in older releases are not yet implemented in this new one. For
>   this solution to work you need to look for a multi arch build of an
>   older version, e.g. **[skype-4-3-0-37-multi-ubu.deb](https://skype.uptodown.com/ubuntu)**

Try this, mate:

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/skype
```

(or whatever your text editor is)

add entry (64x)

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

Save. `Ctrl+O` Close. `Ctrl+X`

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/skype
```

Close terminal. Run Skype.

- This worked for me, Linux Mint 18 Sarah - Xenial Xerus 16.04
- Also tested in Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for pointing out that this won't work anymore in SkypeForLinux.

Comment: I forgot to mention how I solved the problem. So since the software solution doesn't exist, I went towards a hardware one. I've bought an external web camera... and it works flawlessly :)

Comment: Probably a newer version of v4l would've done the job anyway as the below comment from José suggests. Newer linux kernels don't have this problem, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `v4l-utils` package which contains the `v4l2-ctl` utility:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

Verify if your video device supports the vertical_flip option:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls
```

In the output, verify if you see the control vertical_flip.
If so, then edit your .profile:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

And add to the end:

```
# Flip webcam video
v4l2-ctl -c vertical_flip=0
v4l2-ctl -c vertical_flip=1
```

(the double command is intentional)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I followed your instructions but after reboot and login I get a notice saying:

unknown control 'vertical_flip'
unknown control 'vertical_flip'

I also tried to use webcam anyway and unfortunately it's still upside down

Comment: I got to the same place as @VegardSO I ran the command `$ v4l2-ctl -l` and did not see the vertical_flip option listed. In case this helps.